Non-uniquness in buckling problems
I have a doubt. In linear elasticity (geometrically linear and also using linear constitutive law between stress and strain tensors),  we have unique solutions. There is a uniqueness theorem taught in solid mechanics courses.  However, in the buckling of a linear Euler beam, there can be multiple solutions. For instance, consider a straight simple supported beam. We apply displacement at its ends decreasing separation between them. There can be multiple solutions, first mode, and higher modes. Although linear elasticity is valid for small deflections, but still in the vicinity of the planar state, small deflection solutions with higher buckling modes exist. This means multiple solutions for a given separation (irrespective of the stability and preference of the existence of solutions). I am an MS student and found lost between uniqueness and the multiple solutions in the buckling. Where did I go wrong?

Could you please clarify which uniqueness theorem you are referring to? I suppose we need to understand how buckling falls out of its scope to address the question.

The compressed rod has a unique solution, even in a non-linear regime, in which it just gets shorter --- but if the force is large enough that solution becomes  unstable.
This  is no different from one dimensional motion of a particle in mechanics. The solution to $m \ddot x =-\nabla V$ with given initial  $x$ and $\dot x$ is unique. If the particle is sitting stationary at a maximum of $V$ the particle can, in principle, sit there for ever. That is the unique solution. If the initial $\dot x$ or displacement is non-zero, however tiny, then it falls off. Same with the rod. Instability does not conflict with uniqueness.
As to other buckling modes, it is
usually that  first mode to go unstable as the force increases that will be the mode into which the rod buckles. The other nodes only become unstable when the force is larger. A

It is a bit confusing. I am controlling displacement between ends. Assuming that the reaction force at the ends, because of this control, can be large and well beyond what is required for the first buckling point (primary buckling). I am not concerned about the stability of solutions. However, in principle, there are multiple solutions, and this does not go well with uniqueness– at least to my understanding.

If yio set the problem up in different bais (displaceemnet versus force) you cannot expect theorems applied to force vs displacement to be relevent.
